How to use Modus Ponens in L axiomatic system
I have copied a system of axioms for L system described in book Mendelson "Introduction into Logics":
(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

(* We have a single inference rule, namely Modus Ponens. *)

Inductive proof : formula -> Prop :=
| MP : forall A B,
               proof (A ~> B) -> proof A
               -> proof B.

Axiom A1 :
  forall A B,
    proof (A ~> (B ~> A)).

Axiom A2 :
  forall A B C,
    proof ((A ~> (B ~> C)) ~> ((A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C))).

Axiom A3 :
  forall A B,
    proof ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B)).

Lemma L1: forall (A: formula), proof (A ~> A).
Proof.
  intro A.
  assert (H1 : forall A, 
      proof ((A ~> ((A ~> A) ~> A)) ~> ((A ~> (A ~> A)) ~> (A ~> A)))).
  intro A0.
  apply (A2 A0 (A0 ~> A0) A0).
  specialize (H1 A) as H1.
  assert (H2 : forall A, 
      proof (A ~> ((A ~> A) ~> A))).
  intro A0.
  apply (A1 A0 (A0 ~> A0)).
  specialize (H2 A) as H2.

Here we have the following state:
1 goal
A : formula
H1 : proof ((A ~> (A ~> A) ~> A) ~> (A ~> A ~> A) ~> A ~> A)
H2 : proof (A ~> (A ~> A) ~> A)
______________________________________(1/1)
proof (A ~> A)

Now we need to apply H1 to H2 using Modus Ponens.
But when I try specialize (MP H1 H2) as H1 I get an error:
In environment
A : formula
H1 : proof ((A ~> (A ~> A) ~> A) ~> (A ~> A ~> A) ~> A ~> A)
H2 : proof (A ~> (A ~> A) ~> A)
The term "H1" has type
 "proof ((A ~> (A ~> A) ~> A) ~> (A ~> A ~> A) ~> A ~> A)"
while it is expected to have type "formula".


specialize (MP _ _ H1 H2). MP has the form "for all A B, ..." and the placeholders are for the A and B. Alternatively, if you want your original command to work, use this definition instead: Inductive proof : formula -> Prop := | MP : forall {A B}, proof (A ~> B) -> proof A -> proof B.

I would suggest two improvements to your code:

Use implicit arguments, so that you can tell Coq which rule, axiom or lemma to apply without having to specify how to apply it.

Do not use Axiom. You are being thrown off by standard terminology here. An "axiom" in type theory is not what an axiom is in Hilbert-style propositional logic (which is what you're formalizing). The inductive type proof should incorporate the three axioms as constructors directly. The only difference between the A1, A2, A3 and MP is that the latter takes extra premises, and the former do not. But they certainly should all have the same status, namely that of a constructor of proof.


This leads to the following code:
(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

No changes so far, but now we have a better proof:
Inductive proof : formula -> Type :=
  | A1 : forall A B, proof (A ~> (B ~> A))
  | A2 : forall A B C, proof ((A ~> (B ~> C)) ~> ((A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C)))
  | A3 : forall A B, proof ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B))
  | MP : forall A B, proof (A ~> B) -> proof A -> proof B.

Note also that we changed proof to map into Type rather than Prop. This is so because proofs form (an inductively generated) structure that we intend to analyze and work with. If we used Prop, then we would be formalizing provability, which is a certain property of formulas.
Next, we declare that the arguments A, B are implicit:
Arguments A1 {_} {_}.
Arguments A2 {_} {_} {_}.
Arguments A3 {_} {_}.
Arguments MP {_} {_} _ _.

The point is that now, if your goal is something like (Cow ~> Rabbit) ~> Dog ~> (Cow ~> Rabbit) and you say apply A1, Coq will know that it should take A = Cow ~> Rabbit and B = Dog automatically.
I would pull your assertions out as separate lemmas, it's easier to work this way. Also note that I am declaring A to be implicit because it can be read off the statement. And because we declared implicit arguments, the proofs get really easy:
Lemma H1 {A} : proof ((A ~> ((A ~> A) ~> A)) ~> ((A ~> (A ~> A)) ~> (A ~> A))).
Proof.
  apply A2.
Qed.

Lemma H2 {A} : proof (A ~> ((A ~> A) ~> A)).
Proof.
  apply A1.
Qed.

Finally, we can prove your lemma L1. With MP Coq cannot guess the first arguments, so I will use eapply MP which means "apply MP but don't try to figure out its arguments just yet, they will become clear later":
Lemma L1 {A} : proof (A ~> A).
Proof.
  eapply MP.
  - eapply MP.
    + apply H1.
    + apply H2.
  - apply A1.
Qed.

You can also write down a direct proof of L1 by building a suitable element of proof using its constructors:
Definition L1' {A} : proof (A ~> A) := MP (MP H1 H2) A1.


I improved the code further by changing proof so that it maps to Type instead of Prop, see the accompanying explanation.
